# Extract class attribute using xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I have the following html:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdWKrUUAAAAAP3b4V05YVzvFNJNAUrDb0RoJZf7" data-callback="reValidateP" data-expired-callback="reInvalidateP" style="clear:left;">
```

How can I extract sitekey value attribute via Xpath?

Comment: //div/data(@data-sitekey)

Answer (score 1):

XPath 1.0 solution :

```
string(//div[@class="g-recaptcha"]/@data-sitekey)
```

Output : `6LdWKrUUAAAAAP3b4V05YVzvFNJNAUrDb0RoJZf7`